# How do I prevent an asset from being cached by the Rails Asset Pipeline in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I added a custom engine for HAML in config/initializers.

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/page.html it renders the page successfully.

```
# page.html.haml

!!! 5
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

The problem is Rails seems to cache the html asset. When I add or remove a file from the `application.js` manifest it doesn't update until I stop the Rails server and run `rake tmp:clear`. An alternative is to touch the `application.js` file. I have `config.assets.debug = true` set because I prefer to see individual files/folders in Chrome DevTools rather than one big `application.js` file.

Is there a way to exclude certain assets from being cached during development.

Just to reiterate - its the HTML being cached which is the problem, changes to the manifest are reflected when visiting http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/application.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute force solution would be to add some `depends_on` attributes to the haml file:

```
# page.html.haml
#= depend_on application.js
#= depend_on application.css
!!! 5
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

This should force the asset to be regenerated when the `application.js` file is changed.

There are a few cavets with this. The file names should be the names in the source tree. It assumes you can use # for comments in your HAML renderer (I don't know HAML so I'm not sure).I'm also not really sure how this works with a custom engine. Also, a better solution would be to have your custom HAML engine track dependencies itself, but I don't know how to do this.

See the [sprockets docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) for more details

Comment: Brilliant! I actually tried this before and it did not work because I used `//= depend_on`. I just realised that the HAML comment syntax is `-#` and `-# depends_on application.js` works great.